# How can I implement an NIO Channel using only userland memory for transport?

Tags: java, multithreading, nio, channel

**Context:**

I have an application that uses NIO fairly heavily. It has a pluggable transport mechanism, and I am working on benchmarking how various underlying transports perform depending on the transport. IO performance is important, and the app will only be communicated with from other processes on the same computer, so I'm testing with TCP sockets, UDP sockets, `FileChannel`s, and nonblocking wrappers around several UNIX_AF socket libraries.

In order to get these benchmarks, and to perform tests on this system, it would be very useful to have a "fastest possible" control group implementation that traverses the whole server/handling stack using standard NIO functions, but operates at the speed of a thread/memory access.

**Question:**

How can I make a `Channel` implementation that can be used with the rest of the NIO ecosystem, but that only performs in-memory userland operations? Basically, I want to replace the underlying transport system that gets accessed via `epoll`/`select`/`kevent`/etc. with thread-safe data structure accesses.

**What I've Tried:**

I've set up a solution using [`Pipe`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Pipe.html)s (via the default created `Pipe.SinkChannel` and `Pipe.SourceChannel` objects), which is usable for testing.

However, Java tells me the pipes are backed by KQueue channels, and `strace` seems to confirm this. The documentation indicates that Pipes will pick their backend based on the environment in which they are used. As a result, Pipes will not be too useful for benchmarking, as the performance of the `Pipe` implementation will change depending on what OS I'm benchmarking on.

I know that pipes might be faster/more efficient than doing "old-school" passing of data between threads via queue structures, but the second approach is likely much more consistent in performance across host environments.

Comment: I would create a ring buffer in shared memory first using memory mapped files, and then create a SocketChannel implementation to wrap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement ByteChannel, writing the code myself using internally allocated byte arrays as buffers, with synchronized access to ensure flushes to main memory.  This will force a memory copy, which avoids possible efficiencies in nio's byte buffer class and makes the timing more repeatable.

Comment: I'll try that out and accept if it works.

The reason for this particular benchmark is because of the platform dependence. If TCP is faster than UDP by 10x on platform X versus faster by 100x on platform Y, I want to be able to correlate those differences with how _much_ faster each solution is compared to memory access; this helps eliminate differences in performance that are just due to one test platform being faster than the other.

Comment: Your reason for wanting this benchmark makes sense.